# query attachment images … if no attachments -> get attachments of parent page?

Tags: attachments, child-pages, images

I use this to query all attachments of the current page or post I'm on …

```
$query_images_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' =>'image',
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_parent' => $post->ID //$post->post_parent
);

$attachments = get_children($query_images_args);

if ( empty($attachments) ) {
    $query_images_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type' =>'image',
        'post_status' => 'inherit',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_parent' => $post->post_parent
    );
}

$query_images = new WP_Query( $query_images_args );
$images = array();
foreach ( $query_images->posts as $image) {
    $images[] = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image->ID, 'large');
}

foreach ( $images as $image) {
    if ( $image[1] >= 1024 )
        $large_images[] = $image[0];
}

if ( !empty($large_images) ):
```

This works perfectly and queries only the images of the current post or page.

However I have one additional thing I want this piece of code to do:

If a page has no images attached and is a "child-page" of a page that has images attached I want to query the images of the "parent-page".

Again:

parent-page -> has images attached
child-page -> has no images attached -> should query images of the parent-page

This could be done with `$post->post_parent`

```
$query_images_args = array(
            'post_type' => 'attachment',
            'post_mime_type' =>'image',
            'post_status' => 'inherit',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_parent' => $post->post_parent
        );
```

However I have no idea how to differentiate between those two cases.

If a page has images attached I want my code to be `'post_parent' => $post->ID`, if a page is a child-page and has NO images attached I want the code to be `'post_parent' => $post->post_parent`

Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `get_children` to check if it returns anything, then if it doesn't, fetch the parent attachments.

```
//loop stuff

//your $query_images_args

$attachments = get_children($query_images_args);

if ( empty($attachments) ) {

//go get parent attachments 

}else{

//loop through this post's attachments

}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. However I have one last little problem: I did not post my entire code above because it was not necessary for the understanding the question. But I do filter all attachments by its size ( larger than 1024 ) -> I updated my question above with all the code I'm using now. This means … I get all image attachments and do another loop where I only get the images larger than 1024px in width and save them into `$large_images` … this is exactly what I need.

Comment: However is it also possible to query the size of the attachments with the `get_children()` function so I could also get the parent images if the child-page has only smaller images than 1024px? Sounds complicated and I can hardly explain it. Again: Generally everything is working fine now - thanks to your help. However there is one case that doesn't work. If a child-page has images (but those images are small (say like thumbnails)) I also want to get the large images of the `parent-page`. Any ideas on that too?

Comment: Here , on WPSE it best not to edit an already answered question as it goes against the flow of how the site works. It's best to leave your original question and ask a new one, this benefits other users a great deal, thanks!